# 404 error on post, but my server gets the data fine but does not return properly

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to rewrite my login piece with Spring boot. Currently, my data is being posted fine and the backend is getting it, but my success function is not being fired. My backend is throwing no errors, but I am getting a 404 error on the browser.

Here is my post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "login", 
    data: "&username=" + username.value + "&password=" + password.value
}).done(function(response) {
    var resp = JSON.parse(response); 
    if (resp.loginResult === "false") {
        //TODO
    } else {
        //TODO
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (userExists()) {
            session.setAttribute("isLoggedIn", "true");
            session.setAttribute("userID", username);
            session.setAttribute("userType", "employee");
            json.append("{");
            json.append("\"loginResult\": \"true\",");
            json.append("\"resultMessage\": \"Logged in\"");
            json.append("}");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Username or password does not match.");
            json.append("{");
            json.append("\"loginResult\": \"false\",");
            json.append("\"resultMessage\": \"Bad Login\"");
            json.append("}");
        }
        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

I am trying to just return a JSON string which can be parsed on the front end and do whatever needs to be done based off the `resultMessage`. Sorry if my code is ugly, I am still new to Spring and welcome any suggestions!

Here is the error in my console on the browser:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/BedrockWeb/login 404 ()
```

I am assuming I am not returning my JSON string properly.

Comment: why not create an object and then return that object. Spring will convert the object to Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Spring, then use the conveniences that it provides. You can create following class:

```
public class LoginResult {
    private boolean loginResult;
    private String resultMessage;

    public LoginResult() { }

    public String getResultMessage() {
        return resultMessage;
    }

    public boolean isLoginResult() {
        return loginResult;
    }

    public void setLoginResult(boolean loginResult) {
        this.loginResult = loginResult;
    }

    public void setResultMessage(String resultMessage) {
        this.resultMessage = resultMessage;
    }
}
```

Then you have to change your controller method to:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
@ResponseBody
public LoginResult login(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    LoginResult loginResult = new LoginResult();
    if (userExists()) {
        session.setAttribute("isLoggedIn", "true");
        session.setAttribute("userID", username);
        session.setAttribute("userType", "employee");
        loginResult.setLoginResult(true);
        loginResult.setResultMessage("Logged in");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Username or password does not match.");
        loginResult.setLoginResult(false);
        loginResult.setResultMessage("Bad Login");
    }
    return loginResult;
}
```

> The @ResponseBody annotation tells a controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the HttpResponse object. [source](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is because you are not sending JSON response properly.

What you can do is create an object and set the values in that and then try to convert in JSON using

```
new JSONSerializer().transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), java.util.Date.class).exclude("*.class").serialize(object);
```

and send the response to AJAX like below:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(new JSONSerializer().transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), java.util.Date.class).exclude("*.class").serialize(object), HttpStatus.OK);
```

NOTE: If you want to do the same with Spring boot then the @ResponseBody annotation is enough. It will convert the object to JSON.